# How to use XSLT in a search-replace scenario?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file, with certain values in certain locations. I would like to be able to replace/add/remove values at those locations.

The following is given:

1. All the locations reference attribute nodes only.
2. If a location references a non existing attribute node, then the owner element node must exist.
3. The new values are known at the time of writing of the XSL file.

Given those conditions, I have implemented an ad hoc solution that accepts a key-value list in a XAML file, where keys are XPATHs and values are, well, values and does exactly what I need, only to realize, that I have invented a wheel when there is already a Ferrari - XSL transformations.

My question is this. Given an XML, what is the XSL, applying which on that XML does this:

1. Replaces a value at `/a/b/@c` to another value, say `D`. If some `/a/b` elements do not have the `c` attribute - it should be added.
2. Deletes the attribute `/a/d/@e`, if present. Does nothing otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT 1.0:

```
<!-- the identity template copies everything not matched elsewhere -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- special handling for /a/b elements -->
<xsl:template match="/a/b">
  <!-- copy the element itself -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- handle all attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <!-- create (or overwrite!) an attribute named "c" -->
    <xsl:attribute name="c">
      <xsl:value-of select="'D'" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- handle all other child nodes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- empty template to delete /a/d/@e -->
<xsl:template match="/a/d/@e" />
```

Comment: I am checking it now, but it is a bit complicated, because whitespaces are not preserved. Is it possible to preserve all the whitespaces?

Comment: @mark: White-spaces would in fact be preserved with this approach (by the identity template). Can you specify where they are lost for you?

Comment: Everywhere. I am using altovaxml free command line utility to apply the XSL, like so: altovaxml /xslt1 Transform.xslt /in App.config /out 1.xml. The resulting XML file has no whitespaces between the elements - it is all one long line.

Comment: @mark: That's likely a configuration issue with the XSLT processor. Can you cross-checl with MSXSL, please? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2fb55371-c94e-4373-b0e9-db4816552e41&displaylang=en

Comment: Yep, msxsl does output the whitespaces. Thanks.

Comment: @mark: XSLT processors can behave differently, when in doubt check out the configuration options. I'd say dropping white-space should never be the default, but I have no experience with the Altova utility. You can add `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` to have the XSLT processor format the output.

Comment: Mark, unfortunately Altova's XSLT processor respectively probably its XML parser is known to strip white space, see http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?xslt1engineimplementation.htm which says: "The XML data (and, consequently, the XML Infoset) that is passed to the Altova XSLT 1.0 Engine is stripped of boundary-whitespace-only text nodes.". If you want indented output then your only chance is using `indent="yes"` on the `xsl:output`.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest that you may be conceptualising XSL slightly awry here. It sounds as though you're imagining it procedurally i.e. "How do I express 'Do X to Y'" rather than "What is the mapping from structure X to structure Y", which is what XSL really is.

You'll want something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="b">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="c">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$D"/> 
                </xsl:attribute> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(n.b. the "$D" syntax indicates a variable dereference i.e. 'insert the value of variable D'. I'm guessing this is what you want, but you could get D from anywhere.)

So, you don't really need to tell XSL to 'add c' or 'delete e'. You tell it what should be there, and it does nothing otherwise.

Comment: There is no `select` attribute defined on `xsl:copy`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Comment: Blast. Mixing up `copy` and `copy-of`. Fixed. I don't think it warrants a downvote, however.

Comment: Tom, even with the right syntax I don't think your approach with nested for-each is a good one for the posted problem. It doesn't account for other elements potentially being present, it does not handle copying `d` elements but dropping their `e` attributes, it is not flexible and easily extensible. The approach posted by Tomalak with an identity transformation template and then added templates overriding the behaviour for those nodes needing change is the right XSLT way in my view.